# `@TargetApi` vs `minSdkVersion` in Android library

Tags: android, android-library

The short version of my question is: When is it right to use `minSdkVersion` over `@TargetApi` when developing an Android library?

My understanding of `minSdkVersion` in the manifest is that it will block the app from using the library if the app's own `minSdkVersion` is not at least as high. But the app can override the behavior using `tools:override` in their Manifest file.

`@TargetApi` annotates that a class / method is usable only above a certain version, which at a high level is what `minSdkVersion` is doing for the whole library. Lint will check and complain about any usages that are not annotated with `@TargetApi` or wrapped in a `Build.VERSION_CODES` check, resulting in Lint failures if they are violated.

That all sounds reasonable so far, and since all APIs in my library has the same minimum version (26), I set that as my `minSdkVersion`.

But when one of my client apps that has a lower SDK version tries to use us, they are faced with a suboptimal situation: The only way they can use us is if they add `tools:override` in their manifest, but that means they loose all the safety and may accidentally call our API on lower SDK versions.

This leads me to think that I should just omit `minSdkVersion`, and add `@TargetApi` in all of our APIs. Obviously this is tedious to do, but from my client's perspective that's their expected behavior. Furthermore, this conclusion seems to invalidate the purpose for the `minSdkVersion` field in Android libraries, and that all Android libraries should always just omit `minSdkVersion` in the manifest and add `@TargetApi` on all their classes and methods.

- Are there scenarios that I missed where `minSdkVersion` will be preferred over `@TargetApi`? Or at least situations where `minSdkVersion` will be wanted in an Android library in addition to the annotations?
- Is there a way to apply `@TargetApi` in a less tedious way, such as at a per-package level?

Answer (score 0):

**targetSdkVersion**

The targetSdkVersion has nothing to do with how your app is compiled or what APIs you can utilize. The targetSdkVersion is supposed to indicate that you have tested your app on (presumably up to and including) the version you specify. This is more like a certification or sign off you are giving the Android OS as a hint to how it should handle your app in terms of OS features.

For example, setting this value to "11" or higher allows the system to apply a new default theme (Holo) to your app when running on Android 3.0 or higher...

The Android OS, at runtime, may change how your app is stylized or otherwise executed in the context of the OS based on this value. There are a few other known examples that are influenced by this value and that list is likely to only increase over time.

For all practical purposes, most apps are going to want to set targetSdkVersion to the latest released version of the API. This will ensure your app looks as good as possible on the most recent Android devices. If you do not specify the targetSdkVersion, it defaults to the minSdkVersion.

> minSdkVersion <= targetSdkVersion <= compileSdkVersion

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not asking about the `targetSdkVersion` XML attribute. What I want to know is whether there are cases where `minSdkVersion` is preferred for a *library* over the `@TargetApi` annotation

Comment: @MauriceLam he doesn't know.